# Create a permalink to default branch on GitHub

Tags: github

It is possible to change default branch in Github. How one should refer to a file in the default branch?

Let's say a default branch is `alpha` and the file is `/README.md`. 
https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/ tells how to create a permalink to the file with specific branch: https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/alpha/README.md

If I change default branch to `bravo` I will need to update all the links to https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/bravo/README.md which I'd like to avoid. Is it possible?